# Powershell Compare Files from multiple subfolders

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell to compare FILE SIZE from multiple subfolders

Today's files Folder Structure:

- **TodaysFolder as a ROOT FOLDER**
- TodaysFolder/Business/FolderA/  csv files
- TodaysFolder/Business/FolderB/ csv files

I want to compare today's csv file Size from multiple files / subfolders based on yesterday's data

- **Reference Folder Structure:**
- ArchiveFolder/YesterdayDate/Business/FolderA/ CSV files
- ArchiveFolder/YesterdayDate/Business FolderA/ CSV files

Also I plan to implement a condition if file size is <= 5 %, PASS
If file size is > = 10 % size, FAIL

I will post the current code in a few, but just trying to get some ideas and guidance for this project.

```
$TodayPath =  "\\TodaysFolder\Business/FolderA\"
$TodayFiles = get-childitem $TodayPath  -Exclude Archive -Verbose | 
? {! $_.PSIsContainer} |
Select-Object  Name, @{Name='File Size'; Expression={([string]([int]($_.Length / 1KB))) + " KB"}} 


$archiveFolder = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$archiveFolderPath  = "\ArchiveFolder\YesterdayDate\Business\FolderA"

$ArchiveFiles =  get-childitem $archiveFolderPath  -Exclude Archive -Verbose | 
? {! $_.PSIsContainer} |
Select-Object  Name, @{Name='File Size'; Expression={([string]([int]($_.Length / 1KB))) + " KB"}} 


write-host $todayPath -ForegroundColor green
$TodayFiles

write-host "---------------------------" -ForegroundColor Red

write-host $archiveFolderPath -ForegroundColor yellow
$ArchiveFiles



Thanks
```

Comment: What's the date format like? `yyyyMMdd`? `dd-MM-yyyy`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  $archiveFolder = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')

Comment: Should the $ArchiveFolder be used in the path? `$archiveFolderPath = "\ArchiveFolder\$ArchiveFolder\Business\FolderA"`?

Comment: As an aside: In PSv3+ you can now use the `-File` / `-Directory` switches to limit what `Get-ChildItem` returns to files / directories. The solution below uses `-Filter *.csv` to limit matching to CSV files, so `-File` isn't strictly necessary (though would be in the unlikely even that you have _directories_ whose names end in `.csv`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group your file lists by shared file name and process each group in a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) command, where you can compare file sizes.

Note:

- The exact requirements regarding pass / fail based on the percentage of file-size changes aren't clear at this point and neither is whether the calculations should be based on size of today's file or the corresponding archive file.
- The code below assumes that today's files as the basis; see the source-code comments for how to change that.
- The pass / fail logic is limited to passing size-change ratios less than or equal to `.05` (`5%`).
- A custom object summarizing the comparison is output; it outputs rounded *numbers* for the sizes and percentages, but you can easily convert that to *formatted strings*, as shown in the question.

```sh
# Determine $TodayPath and $ArchivePath
# ... 

# Note the use -Filter *.csv to limit processing to CSV files.
# Also, since 'Archive' presumably refers to a *directory* to
# exclude, -Exclude Archive is then not necessary.
# There is no need to select a subset of properties with Select-Object
# at this point.
$todayFiles = Get-ChildItem $todayPath -Filter *.csv

$archiveFiles = Get-ChildItem $archiveFolderPath -Filter *.csv

# Group the two lists by shared file name, and process each group.
[array] $todayFiles + $archiveFiles | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {

  if ($_.Count -eq 1) {
    # File at hand exists only in *one* location - either only in today
    # location or only in the archive location.
    Write-Warning "File has no counterpart: $($_.Group[0].FullName)"
    return
  }

  # Calculate the size change.
  $refIndex = 0  # Base calculation on today's files; change to 1 for archive files 
  $otherIndex = (0, 1)[$refIndex -eq 0]
  $refSize = $_.Group[$refIndex].Length
  $sizeDelta = $_.Group[$otherIndex].Length - $refSize
  $sizeDeltaRatio = $sizeDelta / $refSize

  # Construct and output a custom object with the properties of interest.
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Name = $_.Group[0].Name
    SizeInKb = [Math]::Round($refSize / 1kb, 2)
    SizeDeltaPercentage = [Math]::Round($sizeDeltaRatio * 100, 2)
    Pass = $sizeDeltaRatio -le .05
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @mklement() . I am trying to run your code and not receiving any results back . I passed both paths already

Comment: @PshellUser, not receiving any output would imply that your `$todayFiles` and `$archiveFiles` variables are empty, which is an unrelated problem. Are you really receiving no output at all? As an aside: I've removed the `Select-Object` calls from the solution, because they're not necessary, and have streamlined the `Get-ChildItem` calls.

Comment: that is exactly what I did - by removing select, I was able to get an output. Just trying to understand the logic behind of it a little bit.  Goal is to run this code through multiple folders and compare today's data with previous day setting in archive.

Comment: Output shows a list of files, Size inKB, Size DeltaPercetange and Pass condition, as mentioned on custom object

Comment: @PshellUser, the removal of `Select-Object` shouldn't have made a difference (the later processing only references properties that were selected (`Name`, `FullName`, `Length`), but that's a moot point now. Does it now work as you would expect?

Comment: I found some piece of code which I am looking at the moment right now and made some  updates. Its close to what I am expecting to . I could post the code here or ask a new question on stackoverflow based on this code, what would you recommend ?

Comment: @PshellUser, I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242085/discussion-between-pshelluser-and-mklement0).